# Number of weak components in powers of imprimitive digraphs

Tags: graph-theory, markov-chains, directed-graphs, nonnegative-matrices

Given any strongly connected digraph $G$ and any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ if we let $d(G)$ be the greatest common factor of the lengths of all the directed cycles in $G$ then does the $n^{\text{th}}$ power digraph $G^n$ always have exactly $\gcd(n,d(G))$ weakly connected components?

Where $G^n=(V(G),E(G)^n)$ with $E(G)^n=\underbrace{E(G)\circ \cdots \circ E(G)}_{n\text{ times}}$ via relation composition.

I mean clearly $G^n$ can have at most $\gcd(n,d(G))$ weakly connected components since there is a partition $\{V_1,V_2,\ldots V_{d(G)}\}$ of $V(G)$ for which $E(G)\subseteq V_{d(G)}\times V_1\cup\bigcup_{k=1}^{d(G)-1}V_k\times V_{k+1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the number of components of $G^n$ is always $k = \gcd(n, d(G))$, and in fact they are not just weakly but strongly connected components.

First, here are some results about the existence of walks in $G$ relative to the partition $\{V_1,V_2,\ldots V_{d(G)}\}$.

> **Lemma 1.** For any vertex $v$ and any sufficiently large length $\ell$ divisible by $d(G)$, there is a closed walk of length $\ell$ containing $v$.

**Proof.**  Let $C_1, C_2, \dots, C_m$ be some cycles in $G$, with $C_i$ of length $\ell_i$, such that $d(G) = \gcd(\ell_1, \ell_2, \dots, \ell_m)$. We begin by choosing a vertex $v_i \in C_i$ for each $i$, and finding a walk that goes from $v$ to $v_1$ to $v_2$ and so on to $v_m$, then back to $v$.

This closed walk must have a length divisible by $d(G)$. We can modify its length by adding any of $\ell_1, \dots, \ell_m$ to it any number of times, by inserting one of $C_1, \dots, C_m$ into the walk. Since all sufficiently large multiples of $d(G)$ are sums of $\ell_1, \dots, \ell_m$, all sufficiently large multiples of $d(G)$ can be lengths of a closed walk containing $v$.

> **Lemma 2.** For any vertices $x \in V_i$, $y \in V_j$ and any sufficiently large length $\ell$ such that $\ell \equiv j-i \pmod {d(G)}$, there is an $x,y$-walk of length $\ell$ in $G$.

Begin by finding any $x,y$-path in $G$. Since all edges in $G$ go from one part among $\{V_1, \dots, V_{d(G)}\}$ to the next part, the length of this $x,y$-path is congruent to $j-i$ modulo $d(G)$ as desired. We can follow it up by a closed walk containing $y$ whose length is any sufficiently large multiple of $d(G)$ (by the first lemma).

---

We know ahead of time what the $k$ components of $G^n$ ought to be. They are:

- $W_1 = V_1 \cup V_{k+1} \cup \dots \cup V_{d(G)-k+1}$,
- $W_2 = V_2 \cup V_{k+2} \cup \dots \cup V_{d(G)-k+2}$,
- ...,
- $W_k = V_k \cup V_{2k} \cup \dots \cup V_{d(G)}$.

We can certainly prove that there are no edges between these parts in $G^n$; the hard part is showing that they're strongly connected.

Let $x \in V_i$ and $y \in V_j$ be in the same supposedly-component $W_{i \bmod k}$. By the second lemma, we have an $x,y$-walk of any sufficiently large length $\ell$ satisfying $\ell \equiv j-i \pmod {d(G)}$. By Bezout's lemma, we can find constants $A,B \in \mathbb Z$ such that $Ad(G) + Bn = k$, so that $k - Ad(G)$ is a multiple of $n$. Multiplying by $\frac{j-i}{k}$, we see that $(j-i) - A'd(G)$ is a multiple of $n$. Therefore so are each of $(j-i) + (n - A')d(G)$, $(j-i) + (2n-A')d(G)$,and so forth.

One of these is sufficiently large for there to be an $x,y$-walk of that length. Therefore there is an $x,y$-walk of length divisible by $n$, and by taking every $n^{\text{th}}$ vertex in that walk, we get an $x,y$-walk in $G^n$.

Since this can be done for any $x,y$ in the same part of the partition $\{W_1,W_2, \dots, W_k\}$, we conclude that $G^n[W_1], \dots, G^n[W_k]$ are strongly connected.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help. Also Is it true that $d(G^n)=\gcd(n,d(G))$?

Comment: It is - we can get there in a similar way, but using Lemma 1 rather than Lemma 2.

Comment: (I suppose one extra thing that needs to be said is that the GCD of all the closed walk lengths is the same as the GCD of all the cycle lengths, since each closed walk can be broken up into one or more cycles.)